# Read application.properties from non-component class like pojo or singleton

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using spring boot & for properties I've placed application.properties inside src/main/resources

From @Controllers & @Services, I'm able to read properties, but from my model pojo & a singleton class, I'm not able to read the values.

My @SpringBootApplication is in com.vehicle & I've not overriden @ComponentScan, so I belive it should read all the underlying packages.

Below is code:

**application.properties**

```
vehicle.lift.maxWeight=10
vehicle.lift.error.overWeight=Overweight

vehicle.battery.default=5.0
vehicle.battery.critical.limit=15
vehicle.walk.distance.error=Not able to move
```

**WalkServiceImpl.java** (able to read from here)

```
package com.vehicle.prototype.service.impl;

@Service
public class WalkServiceImpl implements CapabilityService {

    @Value("${vehicle.walk.distance.error}")
    private String mDistanceError;

    @Override
    public void performTask(VehicleData vehicleData) {
        double distance = vehicleData.getWalkingDistance();
        double remainingBattery = vehicleData.getRemainingBattery();

        if (remainingBattery < distance) {
            vehicleData.setErrorMessage(mDistanceError);
            System.out.println(mDistanceError);
        } else {
            vehicleData.setRemainingBattery(remainingBattery - distance);
        }

        VehicleUtil.checkBatteryStatus(vehicleData);

    }

}
```

**VehicleData.java** (Pojo - not able read from here)

```
package com.vehicle.prototype.model;

public class VehicleData {

    private double walkingDistance;
    private double liftWeight;

    @Value("${vehicle.battery.default}")
    private double remainingBattery;

    // setters & getters ....

}
```

**VehicleUtil.java** (Singleton - not able to read from here)

```
package com.vehicle.prototype.utils;

public class VehicleUtil {

    private static VehicleUtil mInstance = null;
    private static Object mLock = new Object();

    @Value("${vehicle.battery.critical.limit}")
    private static double mCriticalLimit;

    @Value("${vehicle.battery.default}")
    private static double mTotalPower;

    @Value("${vehicle.battery.critical.warning}")
    private static String powerWarning;


    private VehicleUtil() {
        // empty private constructor.
    }

    public static VehicleUtil getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            synchronized (mLock) {
                if (mInstance == null)
                    mInstance = new VehicleUtil();
            }
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public static void checkBatteryStatus(VehicleData vehicleData) {
        double criticalMark = (mCriticalLimit * 100.0f) / mTotalPower;
        if (vehicleData.getRemainingBattery() < criticalMark) {
            vehicleData.setBatteryCritical(Boolean.TRUE);
            System.out.println(powerWarning);
        } else {
            vehicleData.setBatteryCritical(Boolean.FALSE);
        }
    }

}
```

Please let me know how to fix this.

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to inject the properties into a spring-managed bean.
What you can do, is to bundle the properties in a bean like this ([see documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html))

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="vehicle")
public class VehicleProperties {
    @Value("${battery.critical.limit}")
    private double mCriticalLimit;

    @Value("${battery.default}")
    private double mTotalPower;

    @Value("${battery.critical.warning}")
    private String powerWarning;
}
```

Then, inject the Vehicle Properties into your service and passe them to VehicleUtil:

```
public class WalkServiceImpl {
    @Autowired
    private VehicleProperties vehicleProperties;

    @Override
    public void performTask(VehicleData vehicleData) {
        ...
        VehicleUtil.checkBatteryStatus(vehicleProperties, vehicleData);
    }
}
```

**Better yet, I would convert VehicleUtil into a managed-bean**

```
@Component
public class VehicleUtil {
    @Autowired
    private VehicleProperties vehicleProperties;
}
```

**VehicleData**

I'm assuming VehicleData is some business object, passed from the client or that you create yourself, for which they are many instances (not just one singleton). In this case, it wouldn't make sense to convert VehicleData into a managed-bean, and its external dependencies could just be provided to it through its setters:

```
public class VehicleData {
    private double walkingDistance;
    private double liftWeight;
    private double remainingBattery;
    // setters & getters ....
}
```

Comment: But what about POJO, should I convert that to @Component as well?

Comment: For VehiculeData it depends, I don't see where you create it. It feels like a business object which you create yourself (or receive from a client tier ?). It doesn't feel like a spring-managed bean. You should provide the properties at creation time. Can you share where/how you create VehiculeData ? Is there many instances or just one singleton ?

Comment: @Alex I believe the private members should not be declared static.

Comment: Agreed! Thanks! it was a copy&paste error from the code snippet in the question :)

Comment: I tried this solution and it didn't work until I added the `@Configuration` annotation to the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation. Any reason why?

Answer (score 0):

Only Instances controlled by Spring are able to get property values injected.

As you have a Spring application you should not write own singleton logic instead of simply annotation `VehicleUtil` by `@Component`. This would also make any usages more testable as you can mock it in a test when the util instance is injected.

You cannot inject a value directly to the `VehicleData` pojo. The property value is mostly a constant during runtime so it can be a default only. You should set the value before exposing in a repo or service or leave it `null` and use the value instead of the non set property wherever it is used.